# how to get an script array value in codeigniter php function via Ajax data:?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var log;
function send_query(check,datashow) {
var values = [];
for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    if (check[i].checked == true) {
        values.push(check[i].value);
    }
}
alert(values);
$.ajax({
type:"POST",

 data: {"data=":values},
 // data : $('[data="values[]"]').serialize()   
 // data:{data: $(values).serializeArray()}, 
 //data:"data="+values,
 url:"<?php echo site_url('grocery/add_to_show');?>",
success: function(html){
    $('#'+datashow).html(html);
}
});
```

in codeigniter controller php function, how to get this script array variable and how to  print that array variable?

please show me a way for my problem

Comment: have you write javascript code in your controller file?

Comment: No, it wrote in view file

Comment: how you call send_query() function

Comment: i called below this type  :                                                                        <input id="a"name="a" type="checkbox" value="1"  onclick="send_query(document.getElementsByTagName('input'),'datashow')" >A</input>
<input id="a"name="a" type="checkbox" value="2" onclick="send_query(document.getElementsByTagName('input'),'datashow')">B</input>
<input id="a"name="a" type="checkbox" value="3"  onclick="send_query(document.getElementsByTagName('input'),'datashow')" >C</input>

Comment: use this to send array to controller in ajax data: { data: values },

Comment: ya i implemented your suggestion, but i cant get result

Comment: sorry use data: { values: values },

Comment: satish rajak... still i can`t get :(

Comment: have you check with this data:values

Comment: function add_to_show()
 {
  $data=$this->input->post('values');
  print_r($data);
  if (is_array($data))
  {
   foreach($data as $d){
       echo $d;
  }
  }
 }

Comment: on controller side you use json_decode($this->input->post('data'));

Comment: but i dont use json it will work ah?

Comment: in controller side use for $val=$_REQUEST['data'] ($i = 0; $i <= count($val); $i++) {

Comment: dude it still notworiking single value passed it returned result

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

## Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var log;
function send_query(check,datashow) {
var values = [];
for (i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
if (check[i].checked == true) {
    values.push(check[i].value);
}
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(values);

$.ajax({
type:"POST",

data: {data : jsonString}, 

// data : $('[data="values[]"]').serialize()   
// data:{data: $(values).serializeArray()}, 
//data:"data="+values,
url:"<?php echo site_url('grocery/add_to_show');?>",
success: function(html){
$('#'+datashow).html(html);
}
});
}
</script>
```

## In your controller

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
```

Comment: sorry, Bipin Kareparambil  i cant get result. please give me another way to solve

Comment: Put a '}' at the end of the script. answer updated. try and let me know its worked or not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $_REQUEST, you can use $this->input->get_post(). even $this->input->post() should work. it is safer.